# OpenERP @http.route('demo_json', type="json") URL not displaying JSON Data

Tags: json, odoo, openerp-8

I am create **controller** in OpenERP Framework. Following is my code and i set *http.route* `type="http"`,

```
import openerp.http as http
from openerp.http import request

class MyController(http.Controller):

    @http.route('demo_html', type="http")
    def some_html(self):
        return "<h1>This is a test</h1>"
```

Above code work perfect once i login into openerp after i modify URL `http://localhost:8069/demo_html` show me return result `This is a test` in h1 heading tag.

But same way i try to `type="json"` and add following json code and again try to call URL `http://localhost:8069/demo_json` Its not work properly and show me error `"Internal Server Error"`.

```
import openerp.http as http
from openerp.http import request

class MyController(http.Controller):

    @http.route('demo_html', type="http") // Work Pefrect when I call this URL
    def some_html(self):
        return "<h1>This is a test</h1>"

    @http.route('demo_json', type="json") // Not working when I call this URL
    def some_json(self):
        return {"sample_dictionary": "This is a sample JSON dictionary"}
```

So my question is how to *route json*. Any help would be appreciate Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is difference between `type="json"` and `type="http"`.

```
type="json":

it will call JSONRPC as an argument to http.route() so here , there will be only JSON data be able to pass via JSONRPC, It will only accept json data object as argument. 

type="http":

As compred to JSON, http will pass http request arguments to http.route() not json data.
```

Comment: you check I'm return JSON data return {"sample_dictionary": "This is a sample JSON dictionary"}

Answer (score 0):

I think , you need to do some extra stuff while working with type="json",you have to trigger that method using json rpc from js.

```
like :
$(document).ready(function () {
    openerp.jsonRpc("demo_json", 'call', {})
            .then(function (data) {
                $('body').append(data[0]);
            });
    return;
})
```

and yes do not forget to return your dictionary in list like

```
@http.route('demo_json', type="json")
def some_json(self):
    return [{"sample_dictionary": "This is a sample JSON dictionary"}]
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me answer. jquery code call on demo_json page head tag inside i add. another things i as per my knowledge JSON return dictonary format to display on page

Comment: Yes you are right JSON retunr dictonary ,but it also return list of dictionary , you can check http://jsonlint.com/ and type something like [{}] and validate.

Comment: @S͢kyD͢ream your question is old 3 years but today in 2017 I want return Json?  How call demo_json  from url and where put above jquery?

Comment: @Pointer we can not update question base on new Odoo update. If you have question ask here directly contact me. Thanks