# How to get JSON data in an Odoo controller?

Tags: json, python-2.7, controller, odoo-8, odoo

I am trying to send some JSON data to an Odoo controller, but when I send the request, I always get 404 as response.

This is the code of my controller:

```
import openerp.http as http
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Controller(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/test/result', type='json', auth='public')
    def index(self, **args):
        _logger.info('The controller is called.')
        return '{"response": "OK"}'
```

Now, I type the URL (*http://localhost:8069/test/result*) on the browser to check if it is available, and I get `function index at 0x7f04a28>, /test/result: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'json' but called with a request of type 'http'`. This way I know that the controller is listening at that URL and is expecting JSON data.

So I open a Python console and type:

```
import json
import requests
data = {'test': 'Hello'}
data_json = json.dumps(data)
r = requests.get('http://localhost:8069/test/result', data=data_json)
```

When I print **r** in the console, it returns *<Response [404]>*, and I cannot see any message in the log (I was expecting *The controller is called.*).

There is a similar question here, but it is not exactly the same case:

[OpenERP @http.route('demo_json', type="json") URL not displaying JSON Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776884/openerp-http-routedemo-json-type-json-url-not-displaying-json-data)

Can anyone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just solved the problem.

Firstly, as @techsavvy told, I had to modify the decorator, to write `type='http'` instead of `type='json'`.

And after that, the request from the console returned a 404 error because it did not know which database it was sending data to. In localhost:8069 I had more than one database. So I tried to have only one at that port. And that is, now it works great!

To manage that without removing any of the other databases, I have just modified the config file to change the parameter `db_filter` and put there a regular expression which only included my current database.

Answer (score 4):

I have just gone through your issue and I noticed that you have written JSON route which is call from javascript. if you want to call it from browser url hit then you have to define router with `type="http"` and `auth="public"` argument in route:

```py
@http.route('/', type='http', auth="public", website=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering @techsavvy, unfortunately, I have modified the decorator of the controller as you told me, but I am still getting the same 404 response.

Comment: @forvas i think you did not have start your odoo service with --db-filter = ur_db_name.

Comment: Yes, I did, if I go to http://localhost:8069/test/result, I can see *{"response": "OK"}*, but if I execute request from Pyhon console, I still get 404.